# Open website, find specific value and return value to Excel in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I would like to use VBA to open a website, look for a certain paragraph in the HTML code of this website (`<p class="myClass">XYZ</p>`) and return this value to Excel, in my example `"XYZ"`.

The website has only one paragraph (p element) with the above class.

I know that this is possible but don't know where to start here.

My code:

```
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
    .Navigate varUrl
    Do While .Busy
          Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Loop
    .Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: can you post the website link?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot post the website link and you would not have access anyways but I could share some of the HTML if this is needed

Answer (score 2):

Instead of opening IE, use a web request:

```
Set oRequest = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
With oRequest
    .Open "GET", sUrl, True
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    .Send "{range:9129370}"
    .WaitForResponse
    Set index = .ResponseText.IndexOf("<p class=""myClass"">")
    Set text = .ResponseText.Substring(index,3)
    Cells(row, col).Value = text
End With
```

If you don't know the length of the string you are looking for, you could also do a loop after `index` until you hit a "`<`" character.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind - thanks so much ! How can I return the resulting value to Excel, e.g. for use in a variable etc. ?

Comment: I defined (Dim) sUrl as string and assigned my URL to it. How do I have to define oRequest here ?

Comment: oRequest is a `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest`. Do you have that library installed? Also, Is this inside an Excel program? If so, you should be able to do something like `Cells(row, col).Value = text`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
    .Navigate varUrl
    Do While .Busy
          Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Loop
    .Visible = True
End With

'HTML document
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = objIE.document

Dim el As Object
Dim myText as string
For Each el In doc.GetElementsByClassName("myClass")
    'put paragrah text in cell A1
    Cells(1, 1).Value = el.innerText

    'put your paragraph text in a variable string
    myText = el.innerText
Next el
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! Do I understand it right that this will list all the element values from the site ? How can I get only the value from the p element with my class and how can I return this to Excel, e.g. in a variable ?

Comment: this returns all object from the page with the class name you specify and puts it in cell A1.

Comment: Thanks again ! This would be good too but when I run it then the Debugger starts on this line: Set doc = objIE.document - How do I have to define (Dim) doc here ?

Comment: Yes, declare it as object.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: the Debugger starts and highlights this line: Set doc = objIE.document

Answer (score 0):

That is a tricky and interesting question. Let's say that you want to obtain the title of this current website, which is in class `question-hyperlink` within StackOverflow. Thus, using the idea of the solution of @Matt Spinks you may come up with something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim oRequest    As Object
    Dim strOb       As String
    Dim strInfo     As String: strInfo = "class=""question-hyperlink"">"
    Dim lngStart    As Long
    Dim lngEnd      As Long

    Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With oRequest
        .Open "GET", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254051/vba-open-website-find-specific-value-and-return-value-to-excel#42254254", True
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .Send "{range:9129370}"
        .WaitForResponse
        strOb = .ResponseText

    End With

    lngStart = InStr(1, strOb, strInfo)
    lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, strOb, "<")

    Debug.Print Mid(strOb, lngStart + Len(strInfo), lngEnd - lngStart - Len(strInfo))

End Sub
```

Instead of `Debug.print` you may get the Title in a string and work further.